# Adapter counting issue with multiple ViewTypes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have an adapter with a number of items to be displayed in a RecyclerView as a list. But I am using adMob to serve ads. So for every x item I want to serve an ad. But the problem I am having is that my adapter is not inserting the ads, but rather serving them **instead** of the item that is supposed to be at said position. How do I fix this problem?

To think of this differently, say my adapter has a list of Pencil items. But for every 5 pencils, I want to show an Egg. So if I have 10 pencils, I want to see all 10 pencils plus 2 eggs: so 12 items. But right now my Adapter is showing 8 pencils and 2 eggs.

I need a general solution to this problem as the adapter may be dealing with a cursor (which is also true in my case). For an ArrayList, I could add dummy placeholders, but for a cursor it is not clear what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like we can divide this into multiple sub-problems.

1) Create a general multi-item-type adapter

There are several ways of doing this, but the solution I usually go for is to create a `ViewHolder` factory/binder that maps item types to `ViewHolder`s:

```
public abstract class ViewHolderBinder<VH extends ViewHolder, T> {
    /**
     * Create a new ViewHolder for this binder's item type
     *
     * @param viewGroup
     * @return
     */
    public abstract VH newViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup);

    /**
     * Bind the data om the given item to the view holder
     *
     * @param viewHolder
     * @param item
     */
    public abstract void bindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, T item);
}
```

Then you create one instance of ViewHolderBinder for every type of item, and your `Adapter` needs to maintain logic to map each type of item to the corresponding ViewHolderBinder, e.g. using a `HashMap<Integer, ViewHolderBinder>`. The mapping could be hard-coded, or better, add a method `addBinder` to initialize your adapter upon construction with item-type-to-binder mappings. 
The item type values could be fixed constants, or, if each type of item is represented by a unique class, you could even use the class' `hashCode()` as the item type to further simplify.

Then create a general adapter that implements `getItemViewType`, `onCreateViewHolder`, `onBindViewHolder` and `getItemCount` using the binder.

2) Let the above adapter handle multiple sources of data

This basically just means you have to implement `getItemCount` so that it combines data from all your sources (say, a cursor + ad provider), and create a method `public T getItem(int position)` that returns the data for the given position. For the item count it should be simple enough just adding up the count from all sources; for `getItem` you have to implement logic to make sure the adapter position is mapped to the index of each respective data source.

In the specific case of every N:th item being an ad, and each ad placed at position k*N, an implementation could look something like this:

```
public T getItem(int position) {
  int adIndex = position / N;

  if (position % N == 0) {
    //TODO return the ad with index adIndex
  } else {
    int dataIndex = position - (adIndex + 1);
    //TODO return data with index dataIndex
  }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
  int dataCount = getDataCount(); // From cursor.getCount() or whatever

  return dataCount + 1 + dataCount / N;
}
```